# API SOAP V2 CatalogProductList Complex Filter with OR

Tags: magento-1.7, api, soap-api-v2, web-services, api-filter

I need to set up a filter with a OR clausule and I don't know how to. Any Help?.

I need to set up the filter manufacturer to filters manufacturer number 34 and 37.

```
Dim pws As New MagentoService.MagentoService
Dim sesionID = pws.login("xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxx")
Dim result

Dim filters As New MagentoService.filters
Dim complexFilter(2) As MagentoService.complexFilter
complexFilter(0) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
complexFilter(0).key = "manufacturer"
Dim assEnt As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
With assEnt
    .key = "in"
    .value = ¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿"34" OR "37"?????????????????
End With
complexFilter(0).value = assEnt

complexFilter(1) = New MagentoService.complexFilter
complexFilter(1).key = "set"
Dim assEnt2 As New MagentoService.associativeEntity
With assEnt2
    .key = "eq"
    .value = "9"
End With
complexFilter(1).value = assEnt2

filters.complex_filter = complexFilter
result = pws.catalogProductList(sesionID, filters, "0")
```

I think I must use the key in and use an array on value, but I can't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `in` complex filter you must specify value in coma separated format (without spaces): `value = '34,37'`.

Comment: Works perfect!!! Thanks!!! Very easy, y try with arrays, parenthesys, etc...